# Jest unit testing a function throwing error

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I was trying to unit test a function in node which throws an error regardless of any condition. Here is my node function definition.

```
public testFunction() {
    throw new Error('Test Error');
}
```

As you can see this function always throws an error whenever it has been called. I tried to execute unit testing to this function using jest [.toThrow(error?)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tothrowerror) method. I was not able to unit test the function as expected.

The below mentioned are the test cases that I wrote and have attached the screenshot of the errors that I faced while executing the same.

**Test Case #1**

```
it('Should throw test error', (done) => {
    const testClass = TestClassService.getInstance();
    expect(testClass.testFunction()).toThrow();
});
```

[image]

**Test Case #2**

```
it('Should throw test error', (done) => {
    const testClass = TestClassService.getInstance();
    expect(testClass.testFunction).toThrow();
});
```

[image]

**Test Case #3**

From [this](http://eloquentcode.com/expect-a-function-to-throw-an-exception-in-jest) blog, it was mentioned that

> If we want to expect a function to throw an exception for certain
>   input parameters, the key point is that we must pass in a function
>   definition and not call our function inside the expect.

So I updated my test case as

```
it('Should throw test error', (done) => {
    const testClass = TestClassService.getInstance();
    expect(() => testClass.testFunction()).toThrow();
});
```

But it was throwing error like

[image]

What is the issue with my implementation? What is the correct method to unit test a function which throws an error object back?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You had it right in your third attempt. The only problem is that you are including the `done` callback in the test definition. This tells the test that it is asynchronous and it expects you to call the `done` callback once the test has finished.

As your test is not asynchronous, it should suffice with deleting the `done` callback in the test definition:

```
it('Should throw test error', () => {
    const testClass = TestClassService.getInstance();
    expect(() => testClass.testFunction()).toThrow();
});
```