# Using Jest to test a function which should throw an error, but always received "function did not throw" error

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I was trying to write a unit test for a simple try-catch structure function. My function is in index.js, and the test is in check.test.js. I am not sure what caused this issue.

Inside of index.js:

```
// index.js

const UNDEFINED_ERROR = "Undefined detected.";
testFn = () => {
    try{ 
       throw new Error(UNDEFINED_ERROR);
    }catch(e){
      console.log(e);
    }
};

module.exports = {
    testFn,
    UNDEFINED_ERROR
}
```

Inside of check.test.js:

```
//check.test.js

const {testFn, UNDEFINED_ERROR} = require('./src/index');

describe('test', ()=>{
    it('show throw',()=>{
        expect(()=>{
          testFn();
        }).toThrow();
    });
});
```

After `npm test`, the test will fail and the terminal will give back `Received function did not throw`.

I referenced this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61285655/jest-unit-testing-a-function-throwing-error), it will perfectly run and pass after deleting try-catch in function, which is just

```
// passed version

const UNDEFINED_ERROR = "Undefined detected.";

testFn = () => {
    throw new Error(UNDEFINED_ERROR);
};

module.exports = {
    testFn,
    UNDEFINED_ERROR
}
```

I am a rookie for JS and Jest and I am really appreciate any help here!

Comment: Your error have been caught in the try catch block and you should not expect `testFn` to throw an error unless re-thrown in the `catch` block. You can assert that `console.log` should be called with `Error`

Comment: Thank you for pointing out! @ Teneff  just solved this by testing my ```console.log()```. Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

If the function doesn't accept arguments, it can be

```
    expect(testFn).toThrow();
```

instead of

```
    expect(() => testFn()).toThrow();
```

The problem is that `testFn` isn't supposed to throw an error, the error is always handled.

It should be:

```
jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
testFn();
expect(console.log).toBeCalledWith(new Error("Undefined detected."));
```

Comment: Thank you @Estus. I think you are right. I shouldn't test throw(). Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to wrap your function call in another method. You were testing that this "wrapper method" was throwing instead of your function itself. Try this:

```
describe('test', ()=>{
    it('show throw',()=>{
        expect(testFn()).toThrow();
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I have tried this before. And this will give me a ```Matcher error: received value must be a function``` This is why I wrap my function inside of the other one.

Comment: There's no way how `expect` could catch an error this way. `testFn()` is evaluated first and fails the test.